# Can I view a template from a pdf?

Tags: pdf

Let's say I am looking at a mathematics paper online in the form a pdf. Is there a way I can extract what Latex template they used? Or is there any way I can figure out what Latex template they are using?

Comment: No.  Some document classes put their name in the pdf meta data but not all. LaTeX doesn't really have anything called a template, it usually just mean an example document demonstrating some collection of packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no. The PDF format isn't limited or tailored to LaTeX, so it doesn't preserve anything from the LaTeX source code. There might be exceptions if the LaTeX source code includes commands to add metadata to the PDF, but the sort of metadata you want isn't part of it by default.

Also, LaTeX doesn't have the concept of template, so I understood your question as being about document class.